# mysql myisam datetime 5.6.10 to 5.5.10 table corruption

Tags: mysql, version, rsync, myisam, corruption

I have mysql version 5.6.10 on one server A where I am creating and populating the myisam table. The created table has int, varchar and datetime fields. When I rsync this table from server A to server B (which has mysql 5.5.10) I get the following error
ERROR 1033 (HY000): Incorrect information in file: test1.frm

For tables without datetime field this process does not give any error. Even when I take the dump for the table from server A and run it on server B it works fine.

Is there any issue with Mysql 5.6.10 version ? How can I resolve this issue ? I cannot afford to take mysqldump for all my tables as it would impact the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is mentioned in [upgrade notes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html) to `MySQL 5.6`

> Incompatible change: For TIME, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP columns, the
>   storage required for tables created before MySQL 5.6.4 differs from
>   storage required for tables created in 5.6.4 and later. This is due to
>   a change in 5.6.4 that permits these temporal types to have a
>   fractional part. After upgrading from MySQL 5.5 to MySQL 5.6.4 or
>   later, it is recommended that you also upgrade from MySQL 5.5 to MySQL
>   5.6 TIME, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP types. ALTER TABLE currently allows the creation of tables containing temporal columns in both MySQL 5.5
>   and MySQL 5.6.4 (or later) binary format but this makes it more
>   difficult to recreate tables in cases where .frm files are not
>   available. Additionally, as of MySQL 5.6.4, the aforementioned
>   temporal types are more space efficient. For more information about
>   changes to temporal types in MySQL 5.6.4, see the section called “
>   Storage Requirements for Date and Time Types ”.

There is also mentioned workaround to get from `5.5` to `5.6` using Memory storage, but it says nothing about downgrading.

Only advice available is from http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71381.

> The only option I see here is to do a dump on the 5.6 of the tables with these temporal columns on 5.6 and then importing them in 5.5